# nginx proxy_pass not working with nodejs server

Tags: node.js, nginx

Trying to put up a server for json requests, the server is `localhost:3000` and would like to redirect any request from `/api/` to `:3000/api/`, but all requests are leading to a `404`.

nginx default:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Here's my server.js express code:

```
app.listen(3000);

app.get('/api/product_groups', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    selly.getAllProductGroups().then((request) => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(request.data));
    });
});
```

Here's my react ajax request using axios:

```
fetchShopData() {
    axios
        .all([
            axios.get('/api/product_groups'),
            axios.get('/api/products'),
        ])
        .then(
            axios.spread((productGroupsRes, productsRes) =>
                this.setState({
                    product_groups: productGroupsRes.data,
                    products: productsRes.data,
                    loaded: true,
                }),
            ),
        );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do a reverse proxy?

Comment: Uh? Not sure what that means. I'm going to access api requests from /api/products to :3000/api/products

Comment: The `try_files` statement is generating the 404 response. Try removing it.